# (UPDATE) : Change of Base Formula or Rule proof

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, solution-verification

I am trying to show that $(s^{w})^{z}=s^{wz}$ using Change of Base Rule.

**My Attempt** : Let $z=\log_{x}(y)\implies y=x^{z}$ and let $w=\log_{s}(x)\implies x=s^{w}$. This automatically means $(s^{w})^{z}$. I am stuck here I hope someone can help me out.

**Update** : One of the users have suggested that I should show that $\log_s((s^{w})^{z}) = wz$ however, after trying to reach a conclusion, I failed. Any more hints or help would be really appreciated

Comment: As you can see, $y = x^a$ means that $\log_x(y) = a$. So, in order to prove that $(s^{w})^{z}=s^{wz}$ it is enough prove that $\log_s((s^{w})^{z}) = wz$, you can do that?

Comment: @azif00 okay so correct me if I am wrong, we have that $\log_{s}((s^{w})^{z})\implies \log_{s}((x)^{z})\implies \log_{s}(y)=wz\implies y=s^{wz}$

Comment: Can we assume that the letters represent real numbers? Because if it involves complex numbers, the property in general does not hold

Comment: ofcourse only real numbers.

Comment: @azif00 can you provide more hint?